# lookup.findvirtual: classParameter is being added as a method parameter

Tags: java, methodhandle

My problem is the following:
I'm trying to use invoke dynamic but I'm having problems with findVirtual and invoke.

```
Class<?> returnTypeClass = Class.forName("com.etc1.foo.FIXML"); 
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();




MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(returnTypeClass ,returnTypeClass); //The method which will be invoked has as a param FIXML object and return a FIXML object

MethodHandle methodHandle = lookup.findVirtual(
                        com.etc2.foo.GMD, 
                        "name_method", 
                        methodType);
```

I have the first problem in findVirtual, I'm getting a methodHandle with the next MethodType (GMD,FIXML)FIXML --> this is not correct because my method is **"public FIXML name_method(FIXML)"** and findVirtual is creating a methodHandle **"public FIXML name_method(GMD,FIXML)"**, I understand findVirtual is using "com.etc2.foo.GMD" as a param.
First question from here: How can I get findVirtual to return a methodHandle FIXML name_method(FIXML)??

The second problem comes from the first one, I think...
When I invoke the method by methodHandle

```
com.etc1.foo.FIXML fixml;
com.etc1.foo.FIXML fixml2;
fixml2 = (FIXML) methodHandle.invoke(fixml);
```

I get the following error "java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(GMD,FIXML)FIXML to (Object)Object"

Actually... I have been looking into other questions and I tried different solutions and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

After breaking my brain for hours I got the answer.
The method findVirtual is returning the correct MethodHandle because the parameter added (**GMD**,FIXML) is, actually, the object which will call the method, therefore I have to invoke the method by:

```
fixml2Obj = (FIXML) methodHandle.invokeWithArguments((Object) Class.forName("com.etc2.foo.GMD").newInstance(), fixmlObj);
```

I share couple links which gave me information about this:

Read "Method handle creation":
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html

http://octodecillion.com/blog/java-reflection-on-a-message-using-methodhandle/

Answer (score 0):

You could also stumble across the same thing when using `invokedynamic`, because the JVM creates parameters that are handed over to the `bootrstrap` method, where method resolution will take place. To circumvent the error you found you will have to remove the class on which the method should be called from the `MethodType` argument.

```
public static CallSite bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup caller, String name, MethodType type) {
    final MethodHandle mh = caller.findVirtual(type.parameterType(0), name, type.dropParameterTypes(0, 1));
    final MutableCallSite callSite = new MutableCallSite(mh);
    return callSite;
}
```